# Using a linear mixed model with only one observation per subject per condition

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I'm running a LMER (in R) on some behavioural data where I have one observation per participant per condition. However, I'm unsure whether it is the appropriate analysis.

The data is in the below format (**note: I cannot break down meanSV into the individual choices it was derived from**):

```
     PID     comparison difference     meanSV 
1 107353   Easy vs Hard  -85.71429 -0.1953125                 
2 107353 Easy vs Medium  -27.27273 -0.0078125                 
3 107353 Medium vs Hard  -58.44156 -0.2578125                 
4 113165   Easy vs Hard -100.00000 -0.9765625                 
5 113165 Easy vs Medium  -50.00000 -0.4453125                 
6 113165 Medium vs Hard  -50.00000 -0.7578125
```

Currently, I have a model trying to predict meanSV from comparison and difference with PID as a random factor. I have not included random slopes as there is only one observation per cell.

```
model <- lmer(meanSV ~  difference + comparison + (1|PID), data = num_SVs_perfDiffs)
```

I am wondering whether this is an appropriate way to tell whether meanSV varies significantly between the three conditions (comparison) and also whether 'difference' is a significant predictor of meanSV (within each comparison group). The output in interpretable and has no errors, but I do not want to be running an analysis which is inappropriate given the dataset.

My instinct was to also include (1|comparison) as a random effect, but this returned a **boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')** error.

Perhaps I should be using a repeated measures ANOVA instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is *meanSV* an average of several measurements/observations?

Comment: It is in a sense, but it wouldn't be appropriate to use the original binary choices here (therefore using a GLMM). To be more specific, meanSV is derived from people's choices between two options in a discounting task (e.g., would you rather do option 1 for $1.00 or option 2 for $2.00. The options they choose between (used to determine meanSV) change on each trial.

Comment: Neither the design of your experiment nor the your encoding of the participants' choices are clear. It seems that there is an order to the choices: easy < medium < hard. You encode this order in *difference*: `Easy vs Medium` + `Medium vs Hard` = `Easy vs Hard`. This is a linear dependency, hence the singular fit error.

Comment: "difference" score is derived from the difference between people's performance in those different tasks (e.g., performance in Medium minus performance in Easy). This is done for each comparison for each participant. 

Sorry if my earlier reply was unclear. I didn't want to go into too much detail about the experiment as I wasn't sure if relevant. The easiest way to consider it is that each participant has one "meanSV" and one "difference" score for each comparison and that I cannot break down the meanSV score. 

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Hi @JakeEmbrey I don't have an answer unfortunately but I have been wondering the same question. If you have any more insight or resources on this problem, please post in the comments, it would be greatly appreciated, thank you!